# input 'hidden' No recoge el valor 'preg_match'

Tags: php

Estoy necesitando enviar una IP por método $_POST a través de un fichero txt que recoge linea por linea:
31.4.191.30 el 12/07/2020 a las 00:48h.
173.252.111.19 el 12/07/2020 a las 00:48h.
31.4.191.30 el 12/07/2020 a las 00:48h.
79.155.174.30 el 12/07/2020 a las 01:45h.
173.252.83.116 el 12/07/2020 a las 05:15h.
181.90.134.179 el 12/07/2020 a las 11:14h.
173.252.111.7 el 12/07/2020 a las 11:57h.
...
Para esto quiero hacerlo fácil y pienso en listar el contenido de esta manera:

```
                        <?php
                        $ips = fopen("connectedDat.php", "r");
                        while (!feof($ips)) {
                            $linea = fgets($ips);
                            preg_match('/\[?([:.0-9a-fA-F]+)\]?/', $linea, $ip); // Extrae solo la IP
                            //echo $ip[1];
                  echo "<form method='post' action='security.php#localip'>
                            <input type='hidden' id='checkip' name='checkip' value='" . $ip[1] . "'>
                            <input type='submit' value='" . $linea . "'>
                        </form>
                        <br>";
                        }
                        ?>
```

Una vez listado el contenido **preg_match** extrae solo la IP correctamente donde la paso al input hidden para enviarla.
Al enviar el formulario, curiosamente no llega el valor **$ip[1]** aunque si el input es **type=text** si que imprime correctamente el valor **$ip[1]**. ¿Me puedes ayudar y decirme en que estoy fallado?. Gracias de antemano!!!

Comment: Corrige el cierre del formulario `</form>` a ver qué pasa.

Comment: No logro entender por qué metes un `a` dentro de ese `input`. En todo caso, revisa el HTML que se está generando. Recuerda que el elemento tiene `checkip` como `name` y que en el POST debes buscar por esa clave. Si no funciona, haz un `var_dump($_POST);` y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: Acabo de corregir el envío del formulario. El `var_dump($_POST);` me muestra `(0) { }` no entiendo como llega un array. Gracias por contestar.

Comment: A. Cedano el propósito de `a` es para mostrarlo como un simple enlace.

Comment: Gracias a los dos, estaba enviando mal el formulario, solución, colocar un botón `submit` adecuadamente.